$L\in P\to L^*\in P$ and the delicate of induction
The question asks to prove that if $L\in P$ then $L^*\in P$.
What I wrote
Notice that $L^*=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}L^k$.
We use induction in order to prove the claim:
Base:
For $L^2$ we can construct a decider $M$ for an input $w=\sigma_1...\sigma_n$ that will iterate through all the pairs of sub words of $w$ and will check if those are accepted by the decider of $L$.
$M$ runs in a polynomial time since the number of sub words in $w$ is polynomial.
Assumption:
There is a decider $M_k$ that runs in a polynomial time and decide if $w_k\in L^k$.
This $M_k$ runs on the same principle as $M$ in the base of the induction.
Step:
Let $w=\sigma_1...\sigma_n \in \Sigma ^*$.
We construct a decider $M_{k+1}$ that will iterate through all the pairs of sub words of $w$ and will check if those are accepted by the deciders of $L^k$ and $L$.
Since those decider runs in a polynomial time and the number of sub words in $w$ is polynomial, we get that $M_{k+1}$ runs also in a polynomial time.
What I'm asking
Is this attempt wrong for the same reason that one cannot use induction in order to prove that the set obtained by a countable union of countable sets is countable?
One can use induction to show that every finite set of countable sets is countable, but the induction will not work if the union goes over $\aleph_0$ sets.
My main struggle is that if someone say that $w\in L^*$ then necessarily $\exists k\in \mathbb{N} : w\in L^k$, something that has been handle in the induction by a decider $M_k$ in a polynomial time.

Given $w =\sigma_1…\sigma_n$ and $1\leqslant i < j \leqslant n + 1$, denote $w_{ij} = \sigma_i…\sigma_{j-1}$.
For each $j>1$, $w_{1j}\in L^*$ if and only if  $w_{1j}\in L$ or there exists $k<j$ such that $w_{1k}\in L^*$ and $w_{kj}\in L$.
This gives the idea of a polynomial time dynamic programming algorithm to find out if $w_{1,n+1} = w\in L^*$.

Your answer is actually the same hint that is given in the question, but this wasn't the topic of the post :)

@Daniel To be honest, I didn't understand clearly what you were asking. You should edit your question to clarify it.

I edited the post in order to to emphasize what I'm asking.

Please let me know if there is still something that isn't clear in what I'm asking.
